# "Attribute only valid on v:image" error on popup

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm implementing a script based on the popup on vector layer example into a cognos report. It all works fine in firefox and i dont get no errors. But if i open my script with internet explorer, as soon as I click on a feature, I can't close the popup anymore and internet explorer crashes with the failure notice: "Attribute only valid on v:image". This happens in both IE 8 & 7.

When i open the regular [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html) i can open/close the popups without an error.

If not for my work i wouldnt care at all that the script can't be used by IE users :)

I hope someone can help.

EDIT: Yes, i've googled before i posted here.

Comment: is there nobody who can help with this ???

Answer (score 1):

Google can tell us a bit more regarding that kind of issue.
It seems the issue can be caused by a third party script. See issue #7 on [Cufon FAQ](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq). That means, your OL code is probably correct. Do you call any other script from the page?

By the way, some users have problems because they use piclens, see that thread : http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-Troubleshooting/browse_thread/thread/983b843c513d46c5

Comment: Hi simo, ive come across the cufon page. its on the first page if you google v:image. Im not using piclens, ive taken an empty report, put in the regular pop vector feature example and thats it. I understand this is caused due to a third party script, but my question is why does it happen. how can i debug the problem, because on the other posts i found, nobody had an answer thats why im asking here.

Comment: Ok. On IE you can click F12 to get the debugging tools. For further details see the debugger tool page : http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/gg589512%28VS.85%29.aspx. By the way, do you have the same bug loading openlayers sample page into IE?

Comment: cool. thx. i didnt know about the F12.